# Why is Linq that slow (see provided examples)

Tags: performance, linq, lazy-evaluation

This Linq is very slow:

```
IEnumerable<string> iedrDataRecordIDs = dt1.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => x.Field<string>(InputDataSet.Column_Arguments_Name) == sArgumentName 
         && x.Field<string>(InputDataSet.Column_Arguments_Value) == sArgumentValue)
    .Select(x => x.Field<string>(InputDataSet.Column_Arguments_RecordID));

IEnumerable<string> iedrDataRecordIDs_Filtered = dt2.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => iedrDataRecordIDs.Contains(
                 x.Field<string>(InputDataSet.Column_DataRecordFields_RecordID)) 
             && x.Field<string>(InputDataSet.Column_DataRecordFields_Field) 
                 == sDataRecordFieldField 
             && x.Field<string>(InputDataSet.Column_DataRecordFields_Value) 
                 == sDataRecordFieldValue)
    .Select(x => x.Field<string>(InputDataSet.Column_DataRecordFields_RecordID));

IEnumerable<string> ieValue = dt2.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => x.Field<string>(InputDataSet.Column_DataRecordFields_RecordID) 
                == iedrDataRecordIDs_Filtered.FirstOrDefault() 
            && x.Field<string>(InputDataSet.Column_DataRecordFields_Field) == sFieldName)
    .Select(x => x.Field<string>(InputDataSet.Column_DataRecordFields_Value));

if (!ieValue.Any()) //very slow at this point
    return iedrDataRecordIDs_Filtered.FirstOrDefault();
```

This change accelerates it by a factor of 10 or more

```
string sRecordID = dt2.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => iedrDataRecordIDs.Contains(
            x.Field<string>(InputDataSet.Column_DataRecordFields_RecordID)) 
        && x.Field<string>(InputDataSet.Column_DataRecordFields_Field) 
            == sDataRecordFieldField 
        && x.Field<string>(InputDataSet.Column_DataRecordFields_Value) 
            == sDataRecordFieldValue)
    .Select(x => x.Field<string>(InputDataSet.Column_DataRecordFields_RecordID))
    .FirstOrDefault();

IEnumerable<string> ieValue = dt2.AsEnumerable()
   .Where(x => x.Field<string>(InputDataSet.Column_DataRecordFields_RecordID) == sRecordID 
        && x.Field<string>(InputDataSet.Column_DataRecordFields_Field) == sFieldName)
    .Select(x => x.Field<string>(InputDataSet.Column_DataRecordFields_Value));

if (!ieValue.Any()) //very fast at this point
    return iedrDataRecordIDs_Filtered.FirstOrDefault();
```

The only change is that I store the result directly in a new variable and use create the where clause with this value instead of a LINQ query (which should be calculated when needed). But LINQ seems to calculate it in a bad way here or am I doing something wrong?

Here some values of my data

```
dt1.Rows.Count                     142 
dt1.Columns.Count                    3 
dt2.Rows.Count                     159 
dt2.Columns.Count                    3 
iedrDataRecordIDs.Count()            1 
iedrDataRecordIDs_Filtered.Count()   1 
ieValue.Count()                      1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking why

```
IEnumerable<string> iedrDataRecordIDs_Filtered = data;    
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    // do something with
    iedrDataRecordIDs_Filtered.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

is slower than

```
string sRecordID = data.FirstOrDefault();
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    // do something with
    sRecordID;
}
```

Very simply because you're evaluating the `iedrDataRecordIDs` collection every time you get the `FirstOrDefault`. This isn't a concrete object, it's an enumerable set. That's really just a function that returns some objects. Every time you query it the function will be called and you'll pay that execution cost.

If you change

```
IEnumerable<string> iedrDataRecordIDs_Filtered = dt2.AsEnumerable()... 
var recordIDs = iedrDataRecordIDs_Filtered.ToList();
```

and then use `recordIDs.FirstOrDefault()` you'll see a huge performance increase.

Comment: So you advice me to use ToList() creating a List<T>. Wouldn't that cost too much?

Comment: If you only ever need the first item then select the first item (your second, faster performing example). I assumed that you'd need all the items that you identify at some point, otherwise why are you creating an `IEnumerable`?

Comment: re: "cost too much" - that depends on so *many* things, but if the items are already in memory then it won't cost a huge amount of memory - just the references - nor time. My advice is to focus on what you need to do! If you only need the first item, just get the first item, put it in a local variable and then use it instead of getting confused with `IEnumerable` objects. If you need to iterate through all items more than once, put them in a list.